# Multiplexer handling 16 bits

Tags: circuit-design, multiplexer, register, decoder

Design the VHDL components (Register, Decoder, and two Multiplexer 16 bit) and interconnect them to build a register file. The schematic shows only four registers.  Your solution should implement eight registers.

[image]

The diagram provided as an example uses a 2:1 and 4:2 multiplexer, this deals with 4 bits. Now that I have to create a circuit with 16 bits, what are my inputs into the multiplexer, in relation to VHDL code?

I've completed a sketch of the circuit, is it correct?

[image]

I did the VHDL code for the first multiplexer:

```vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL; 

entity mux8_16 is   
    Port(in0,in1,in2,in3,in4,in5,in6,in7: in std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);  
         s0, s1, s2: in std_logic (1 downto 0);   
         z: out std_logic_vector (15 downto 0));  
end mux8_16;  

architecture behavioural of mux8_16 is  
begin  
    z <= in0 after 5ns when s0 = '0' and s1 ='0'  and s2 ='0'else  
         in1 after 5ns when s0 = '0' and s1 ='0'  and s2 ='1'else   
         in2 after 5ns when s0 = '0' and s1 ='1'  and s2 ='0'else   
         in3 after 5ns when s0 = '1' and s1 ='0'  and s2 ='0'else   
         in4 after 5ns when s0 = '0' and s1 ='1'  and s2 ='1'else  
         in5 after 5ns when s0 = '1' and s1 ='0'  and s2 ='1'else   
         in6 after 5ns when s0 = '1' and s1 ='1'  and s2 ='0'else  
         in7 after 5ns when s0 = '1' and s1 ='1'  and s2 ='1'else   
         '0000000000000000' after 5ns  
end behavioural;
```

Is the code the right format?

For the decoder is this correct?

```vhdl
entity decoder_3to8 is  
        Port(din:in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);  
        dout: out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0));  
end decoder_3to8;  

architecture behavioural of decoder_3to8 is  
begin  
    dout <= ("10000000") when (din="000") else   
            ("01000000") when (din="001") else   
            ("00100000") when (din="010") else   
            ("00010000") when (din="011") else   
            ("00001000") when (din="100") else  
            ("00000100") when (din="101") else   
            ("00000010") when (din="110") else  
            ("00000001") ;   
end behavioural;
```

Is this code correct for the instance of a regsiter?

```vhdl
architecture GEN of REG_BANK is     
component REG     
    Port(Load,Clk,D :in std_ulogic;    
        Q : out std_ulogic);    
end component;    
begin    
    GEN_REG:     
    for I in 0 to 7 generate     
        REGX : REG port map    
           (LOAD,CLK,DIN(I), DOUT(I));       
        end generate GEN_REG;     
end GEN;
```

Comment: Why not start by putting 8 registers  instead of 4, and expanding the input decoder and output mux to make them handle 8 ways? Also expand the width of all data busses to 16. Done.

Comment: Okay I''ll do that now, however do you mean change 4 registers to 8 registers? does that mean I'll have one 8:1 multiplexer and then a 2:1

Comment: @dim also is (3:0) for all eight registers and multiplexers?

Comment: Yes, I didn't read the text very carefully. I mixed the bit width and the number of registers (I updated my comment). As I understand, you need both to increase the number of register to 8 and the bit width to 16, right? (it's not quite clear) So you need a decoder_3to8 instead of the 2to4 and probably a mux8_16bit instead of the mux4_4bit and a mux2_16bit instead of the mux2_4bit. If these basic blocks aren't there, you need to make them out of smaller ones, but you know how to do that, right?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a homework question. As such, you need to show us your work so far, and explain which part of the question you're having trouble with. For future reference: Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment. We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of your own. Otherwise, we would be doing you a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time. See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Comment: @Dim I completed a sketch of the circuit. Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: @Sue As for the sketch, it looks like what I'd do. Regarding VHDL code, I'm more proficient with Verilog, so I can't tell about the syntax, but the gist seems right. Maybe i'd just replace the ending *"else in7 after 5ns when s0 = '1' and s1 ='1'  and s2 ='1' else '0000000000000000' after 5ns"* simply by *"else in7 after 5ns"* since you've covered all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is clearly homework, I'm just going to provide hints that guide you toward a solution:

Perhaps you should start by writing the VHDL for the circuit as shown. Then, try to understand which parts of the code pertain to the width of the data buses, and which parts pertain to the number of registers.

Comment: I provided my solution, on which I think the circuit should look like, do I have the right idea?

Comment: Yes, that's the general idea. Now turn it into VHDL.

Comment: I edited the question above with the VHDL, is it correct?

Comment: Almost. The s0, s1 and s2 input ports are single wires -- get rid of the `(1 downto 0)` in that line. Although it would be more idiomatic to make it a single 3-bit port: `s: in std_logic_vector (2 downto 0)`

Comment: I added the code for the decoder, is it correct?

Comment: Not to my eye. If you want output bit 0 to be activated when the input has the binary value 0, then you need to flip your output patterns. You've declared bit 0 to be on the right -- that's what `dout: out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0)` means.

Comment: I added the code ive generated for the registers above, is it correct?

Comment: You need to start formatting your code correctly yourself. Edit your post, select the block of new code, and hit the button that looks like "{}" (or use the keyboard shortcut CTRL-k). This will indent every line by 4 spaces and cause Markdown to format it as preformatted text.

Comment: I've indented the code, am I going in the right direction?